# My default face only supports one size

Tags: faces

I am trying to restore the face scaling functionality I had in previous versions of Emacs.

On Ubuntu 22.04, Emacs (not 30!)  master branch d4d6830f8a0. Tested on tag `emacs-29.2` with the same result.

I installed terminus like this:

```
sudo apt install xfonts-terminus
```

My init file does this:

```
(when (member "Terminus" (font-family-list))
  (set-frame-font "Terminus:size=18" nil t)
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Terminus:size=18")))
```

No matter what size I set, my emacs buffers always look the same. I've try to write `height` instead of `size`, no difference.

How do I change the size of my emacs face? Do I need to install different font sizes at system level?

---

Edit: I previously set the default face like this:

```
(when (member "Terminus" (font-family-list))
  (set-frame-font "-xos4-Terminus-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-c-60-iso10646-1")
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "-xos4-Terminus-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-c-60-iso10646-1")))
```

If I replace `12` with `18`, I do get a difference. `text-scale-decrease` does have an effect then, but it's weird, the decrement/increments are very small, not all characters are supported, it sometimes switches to italics... Which makes me think that this is not the correct way.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not running Emacs in a terminal are you?  You're using GUI Emacs frames?

Comment: @phils Correct!

Answer (score 1):

[Terminus is a bitmap font](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/xfonts-terminus); it only supports specific sizes. If you want a font that can scale to any arbitrary size, find a vector (TrueType or OpenType) font that you like.

From the package description:

> This package contains normal and bold fonts in the following sizes: 6x12, 8x14, 8x16, 10x20, 11x22, 12x24, 14x28 and 16x32 and supports the following encodings: ISO10646-1, ISO8859-1, ISO8859-2, ISO8859-5, ISO8859-9, ISO8859-13, ISO8859-15, ISO8859-16, KOI8-R, KOI8-U, CP1251 and PT154.

Also from the description:

> Note: You might want to use the package fonts-terminus-otb instead of this package because the fonts in this package are used by the X server directly. Several modern applications will ignore such fonts.

Emacs won't ignore server–side fonts, but while it does install OpenType fonts they’re still bitmap fonts and not vector fonts.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably my problem. I installed `fonts-terminus-otb`, but could not find it later in `(font-family-list)`. Not sure why not.

Comment: Presumably they’re the same font family and font name. It’s just that one is in PCF format which the X server can load, and the other is in OpenType format that Emacs can load directly but the X server cannot.

Comment: Ok! So what is the implication in my case, that the terminus-otb version is in practice not usable for me either?

Comment: You just need to use a different font.

Comment: Not the response I was hoping for :) No hope for terminus? Or other fonts without aliasing?

Comment: How could you hope for any other answer? It’s a bitmap font, and there is no 18px version for it to use. It can’t use a font that doesn’t exist.

Comment: The thing is that gnome-terminal does it, no problem. So I wouldn't call it impossible. And it's not interpolating, it's real pixel-true characters.

Comment: But I now can use multiple sizes, if I write them in the init file. `text-scale-increase` does not work though. That's probably for another question.

Comment: Here goes: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80802/cannot-rescale-frame-font