# Cannot rescale frame font

Tags: fonts

Ubuntu 22.04, Emacs 30-ish.

I set my font this way:

```
(when (member "Terminus" (font-family-list))
  (set-frame-font "-xos4-Terminus-normal-normal-normal-*-14-*-*-*-c-60-iso10646-1")
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font
                      . "-xos4-Terminus-normal-normal-normal-*-14-*-*-*-c-60-iso10646-1")))
```

I installed terminus with the `apt` packages `xfont-terminus` and `fonts-terminus-otb`.

My problem: I cannot increment or decrement the frame font size interactively anymore. `text-scale-increase` does nothing (event called many times). My previous zoom functionality does not work either:

```
;; --- Zoom applies to the whole frame ---
; Taken from a comment in package frame-cmds.el (elpa). Probably not working for versions under 22.
(defun my-enlarge-font (&optional increment frame)
    "Increase size of font in FRAME by INCREMENT.
Interactively, INCREMENT is given by the prefix argument.
Optional FRAME parameter defaults to current frame."
    (interactive "p")
    (setq frame  (or frame  (selected-frame)))
    (set-face-attribute
     'default frame :height (+ (* 10 increment)
                               (face-attribute 'default :height frame 'default))))
(defun my-zoom-in ()
  (interactive)
  (my-enlarge-font 1))
(defun my-zoom-out ()
  (interactive)
  (my-enlarge-font -1))
```

My best guess is that something with `:height` now works differently, but it's a long shot.

What can I do to restore my zoom functionality?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try is a different font (family). IOW, check whether this breakage is general or specific to terminus.

---

Text scaling works differently from the font-enlarging code you show. If `text-scale-increase` also doesn't work then it smells a bit like a bug/regression introduced in Emacs 30. If you don't get a good answer here, maybe try filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

---

I don't have Emacs 30 (and it's not yet a release), so I don't know if this too is being broken by underlying "progress". But in case it does still work...

Your `my-enlarge-font` code looks very much like my `enlarge-font` ;-). You can try that, to see if it too becomes broken by Emacs 30.

It's defined in [`frame-cmds.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el), which in turn requires [`frame-fns.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-fns.el).

I'll be interested to find out what you find out, wrt the breakage and possible fixes/workarounds for it.

---

For interactive use, there is also [`zoom-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el), which uses `enlarge-font` from [`frame-cmds.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el).